# Current Time IF statement GT ThrustLag

Tags: java, time, if-statement, long-integer

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() >  _thrust_lag + _thrust_delay);
    {
        this._thrust3Position = new_Position;

        Log.w("Thrust Lag + Delay", Long.toString(_thrust_lag + _thrust_delay));
        Log.w("Current Time", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        _thrust_lag = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

The output is:
Thrust Lag + Delay : 1333710037096
CurrentTime :        1333710027174

_thrust_delay = 10000 btw.

This should return false but it's not, it keeps outputting this statement. Anyone any ideas? Or am I missing something fundamental here?

All the variables within this statement are longs, also _thrust_lag only gets set once in the constructor and in this function, so the problem lye's here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trailing `;` at end of `if` statement: remove it.

The trailing `;` semi-colon results in a branch with no statements being executed:

```
if (...);
```

is same as:

```
if (...)
{
}
```

This means in the posted code the statements within the `{}` are always executed.

Comment: OMG something that simple, I was looking at this for like 30 minutes and thinking WTF? Thanks alot!